# Filtering with deep nested items

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping:

```
PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "parent": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "@id": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "@type": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "child": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "@id": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "subchild": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                    "@id": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "hasA": {
                      "type": "nested",
                      "properties": {
                        "@value": {
                          "type": "string"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "hasB": {
                      "type": "nested",
                      "properties": {
                        "@id": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "hasC": {
                      "type": "nested",
                      "properties": {
                        "@id": {
                          "type": "string",
                          "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the following document:

```
POST /test/test/1
{
  "parent": {
    "@id": "12345",
    "@type": "test",
    "child": [
      {
        "@id": "1",
        "subchild": [
          {
            "@id": "1.1",
            "hasA": {
              "@value": "hasA value"
            },
            "hasB": {
              "@id": "hasB_1"
            },
            "hasC": {
              "@id": "hasC_1"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@id": "2",
        "subchild": [
          {
            "@id": "2.1",
            "hasA": {
              "@value": "hasA value"
            },
            "hasB": {
              "@id": "hasB_2"
            },
            "hasC": {
              "@id": "hasC_2"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And the following query:

```
POST test/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "parent.child.subchild.hasB",
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "parent.child.subchild.hasB.@id": "hasB_2"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "_cache": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm unable to set the path to just parent.child.subchild so that I can match on both hasB and hasC, it seems I can only select one nested item at a time. This is what I would like to be able to do:

```
POST test/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "parent.child.subchild",
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "parent.child.subchild.hasB.@id": "hasB_2"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "parent.child.subchild.hasC.@id": "hasC_2"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "_cache": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @AndreiStefan I noticed you reformatted my json, which tool can I use in the future to ensure my json is properly formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "parent.child.subchild",
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "parent.child.subchild.hasB",
                    "query": {
                      "term": {
                        "parent.child.subchild.hasB.@id": "hasB_2"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "parent.child.subchild.hasC",
                    "query": {
                      "term": {
                        "parent.child.subchild.hasC.@id": "hasC_2"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "_cache": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: as always perfect! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Query for correct syntax for multi-level nested docs can be found [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11830). Look at @martijnvg comments inside it.

ES Docs has not done a good job on explaining multi-level nested query.
Basically you need to nest subchild inside child inside parent and specify individual `path`. You will need three nested queries.

P.S - I have not tested this myself. Please let me know if it does not work.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it didn't work. The only way I've been able to query nested items is to not make the last item nested (subchild) and instead define it as an object.